# Getting feedback from a JavaScript application without a registering for a centralized service

Tags: javascript, post, message-queue, messaging

I created a Chrome extension which is just HTML/CSS/JavaScript. When the user clicks on a button, I have it send a message to me. But the problem is I don't want to include any API keys or server information where the app can POST to as it can be used for abuse if someone was to extract this information from my Chrome app. Is there a method of getting a response from a web app with a public service where anyone can post to? I was thinking pastebin, but even that requires an API key.

Comment: No, you need a server of your own for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the user to create their own key. For example, many GitHub extensions require an API key to make requests to the GitHub API, so what they do is they send you to a GitHub settings page where you can create a personal API key.